# How do I solve the error which I get during training the clients in flower framework for federated learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated, flower, federated-learning

I am trying to implement Federated Learning using Flower framework in python. I get the following error when I start the process.[Snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9fJU.jpg)

Here is what I tried,

```
NUM_CLIENTS = 10

#function to load data
def load_datasets(num_clients: int, train_loader, test_loader):

    
    # Split training set into `num_clients` partitions to simulate different local datasets
    partition_size = len(train_loader) // num_clients
    lengths = [partition_size] * num_clients
    datasets = random_split(train_loader, lengths, torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))

    # Split each partition into train/val and create DataLoader
    trainloaders = []
    valloaders = []
    for ds in datasets:
        len_val = len(ds) // 10  # 10 % validation set
        len_train = len(ds) - len_val
        lengths = [len_train, len_val]
        ds_train, ds_val = random_split(ds, lengths, torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
        trainloaders.append(DataLoader(ds_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True))
        valloaders.append(DataLoader(ds_val, batch_size=32))
    testloader = DataLoader(test_loader, batch_size=32)
    return trainloaders, valloaders, testloader


trainloaders, valloaders, testloader = load_datasets(NUM_CLIENTS ,train_loader,test_loader)



#client function thats been passed to start the server 
def client_fn(cid) -> CardiacClient:
    net = CardiacModel().to(DEVICE)
    trainloader = trainloaders[cid]
    valloader = valloaders[cid]
    return CardiacClient(cid, net, trainloader, valloader)
```

In the above code cid refers to the clientID,

Answer (score 0):

When invoking the Client function within the main function, ensure that the parameter **cid** is either an integer or a slice, and not a string. It's easy to inadvertently pass a string representation of the number, such as "2", instead of the actual integer value 2. To rectify this issue, make sure to pass 2 as an integer instead of "2", as the correct data type for cid is an integer.

By ensuring that the correct data type is used, you will prevent potential errors and ensure the proper functioning of your code.